# Android ViewPager onPageSelected() fired too early

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I'm using [Android Tutorial Bubbles library](https://github.com/lovoo/android-tutorial-bubbles) to add informative bubbles referring to views in my UI. My main UI consists of three tabs using a `ViewPager`. And I would like the tutorial for the second tab to begin only when the user navigates to that tab. I am able to catch the event that the user navigates to the tab using an `OnPageChangeListener`.

The problem is that the `onPageSelected()` method fires before the views are in their correct positions, meaning that the highlighted area that is supposed to surround the view of interest is significantly shifted. I could solve this using `Thread.sleep()` for a short period of time; is there a cleaner way of handling this?

Here's my code:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 1) {
                sensorReadingFragment.showTutorial();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: As far as I understand you want to wait until the animation ends.. Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892403/android-viewpager-animation

Comment: That word perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can delay it as

```
 pager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pager.setCurrentItem(position_tab);
           // Perform your operations
        }
    });
```